# Raspberry pi: How to toggle a thermal heater

Tags: python-3

I am trying to build a thermal heater and controller. I have a thermal blanket (https://www.adafruit.com/product/3670) and I would like to be able to control the current to the blanket by control it turning on and off using a raspberry pi, connected to some sort of electronic toggle. Is this the right place to look for such knowledge?

Comment: How much power, specifically how much voltage and current are you planning on applying to this product?  That will determine what power switching device you need.  The Pi itself can only supply a few mA at 3.3V so powering the heater with the Pi is not possible.  What you need is probably a relay and a relay driver connected to the Pi.  Please supply more details and something more specific could be recommended.

Comment: Hello @Perry Godse, Welcome and nice to meet you. Ah let me see. Your "thermo heater" at 12VDC uses 3W per square inch, so it it pretty "safe". References: 
(1) "EeonTex High-Conductivity Heater Fabric - AdaFruit $13":
https://www.adafruit.com/product/3670,

(2) "Conductive Heater Fabric - Sophy Wong, AdaFruit"
https://learn.adafruit.com/experimenting-with-conductive-heater-fabric,

(3) "EeonTex Conductive Nonwoven Fabric - EeonTex""
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/3670/NW170-PI-20+TDS.pdf. Cheers.